# Hide div with custom data attribute number below selected option

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create a filterable list where you can select a `min` and `max` number and hide items that do not fit within the two options. At the moment I'm just focusing on the minimum value.

I have a select box with numbers 1-4:

```
<select class="bedroom-min">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

And I have a number of items that have `data-bedrooms` set to a value:

```
<div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="3">3 bedrooms</div>
```

In the above example, I want to `fadeOut` the above element if the `select` option `4` or `5` is shown, as anything below the minimum number should not be shown.

I have tried the following:

```
$(".bedroom-min").change(function() {
  var minValue = $('select.bedroom-min').val();
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item[data-bedroom<' + minValue + ']').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

The selector is supposed to select a bedroom number data less than `minValue`, but it does nothing, though there is no error.

Any ideas?

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/XmxqQG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter() function to filter the elements based on their value so in this case you want to display the elements whose values are greater than or equal to the minValue and hide the rest.

**HTML**

```
<select class="bedroom-min">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div class="property-load-section">
   <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="5">5 bedrooms</div>
   <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="4">4 bedrooms</div>
   <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="3">3 bedrooms</div>
   <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="2">2 bedrooms</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("select").change(function() {
  var minValue = $('select.bedroom-min').val();
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') < minValue;
  }).fadeOut('fast');
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') >= minValue;
  }).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjxKoO)